# A value of type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<problemModel>'

Tags: flutter, dart, search

Can anyone help me I've been stuck with this for days before then stuck with this. duplicateItems and I have added List duplicateItems = []; And then comes the problem with this:  A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'

```
class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
   Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      getAllProblem();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void _filterSearch(String query) {
    List<String> duplicateItems = [];
    setState(() {
      problemlist = duplicateItems
          .where((problemlist) =>
              problemlist.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you really think List<problemModel> and List<String> are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states

> List<String> and List<problemModel> are not the
> same.

Consider changing:

```
List<String> duplicateItems = [];
```

to

```
List<problemModel> duplicateItems = [];
```

Comment: I did as you said and got stuck on toLowerCase // The method 'toLowerCase' isn't defined for the type 'problemModel'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toLowerCase'. which I have reworked also stuck with the problem

Comment: Normally you should raise a different question. In this case List<problemModel> has object as a type for each Element in the list. To Lower case isnt a object function it's a string function. In this case you should use a object property e.g problemList.name.toLowercase.... Depending what properties you have set. If it's not a string you could use toString() and then to Lower case